# Error When Parsing sLine String into Integer

Tags: java

This code is just a file reader, and it does not show any errors, however when i go to run it, an error seems to occur on this line: int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(temp[x]);

Why is it seemingly unable to parse this variable into an integer?

```
public void loadRecordTimes(){

    //get each time from the text file
    try{
        File f = new File ("Times.txt"); 
        //appends content to file
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        //bufferedwriter writer give better performance
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        //reads a line from the text file
        String sLine = br.readLine();

        //as long as something was read from the file, it will keep running
        while (sLine != null){               
            //take the line that was read and split it based on on the comma
            String[] temp = sLine.split(",");

            for (int x = 0; sLine != null; x++){        

            System.out.println(temp[x]);

            int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(temp[x]);
            //adds recorded times from content file to array
            recordTimes.add(temp2);

            }

            sLine = br.readLine();     
        }

    br.close();
    fr.close();

    }

    catch(IOException e){

    System.out.println("Exception occured:");
    e.printStackTrace();

    }    

}
```

This is the error message that my IDE has given me if this helps:

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at GlobeTrotter.loadRecordTimes(GlobeTrotter.java:912)
        at GlobeTrotter.<init>(GlobeTrotter.java:54)
        at GlobeTrotter$22.run(GlobeTrotter.java:1460)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Can you show us the txt file you are trying to read from?

Comment: This is all the text file contains: "24,45,32,80,54,76,90,"

Answer (score 0):

To fix NumberFormatException, simply remove any whitespace at the end of your text file. The exception is thrown when you try to parse the space or newline at the end.

After you do that, there is another error in the code in the line:

```
for (int x = 0; sLine != null; x++){
```

sLine != null is not the right stopping condition since it is always true when the compiler reaches this line.As such it continues after it reaches the end of the array and will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException

To fix that replace it with:

```
for (int x = 0; x < temp.length; x++){
```